# How I can pass a parameter in a graphQL apollo client query that will be used by one of the graph nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I have a graph node called vat that accepts parameters, if I use this query in playground forcing a country parameter works, but in react, when I'm using apolloClient, this countryCode parameter is not arriving to vat node. What I am doing wrong?
I've been searching a lot of documentation but I don't find the solution, either in the apollo client documentation.

```
const QUERY_PRODUCT = gql`

    query getProductInfo($productId: String, $productHasStock: Boolean, $countryCode: String) {
        searchProducts(productId: $productId, productHasStock: $productHasStock, countryCode: $countryCode) {
            products {
                vat(countryCode: $countryCode) {
                    vatAdjustmentPercentage
                    customerVatValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

Thanks!

Comment: ... and react code? variables, how passed?

Comment: Give us the API query resolver code and code where you call that query

Comment: It was solved thabks. There was a problem with the schema that share the country code in different parts, one of them with ! And there was a conflict. Thanks for the answers